Hello , in Microsoft Fabric i am unable to configure a connection with SQL Server Database. its showing Error instance related
I want to Fetch and store data from SQL Server database to Data-lake using Microsoft Fabric but i could not able to make connection with SQL Server Database.
Thanks for help!
I have followed these steps :-

I have created new data lake
using new created pipeline, for copy data into lake house asking for Choose Data Source, So i have entered all the details like Server Name, Database Name, Username, Password. But its showing error, not moving to next step.


Can you share the error message


If you are trying to connect SQL server, then you should connect it through data gateway only. Otherwise, you will get error here.


A data gateway is a component that acts as a bridge between your on-premises data sources and Azure services. It provides a secure way to transfer data between your on-premises data sources and Microsoft fabric.

Install the on-prem data gateway on the same network where SQL server is located.

Authenticate the data gateway and then use the same gateway name in the connection credentials as shown in the above image.


Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-sql-server-database

Great to know, this helped
